# Timer in C# - Saving time when winning the game

Tags: c#, timer, windows-forms-designer

Im making a game project on Visual Studio (Windows Form). I choose Minesweeper and it is going pretty well so far. Ive watched a lot of tutorials about it and I already made the game. Now I added a timer in the form so when the user starts playing it counts the time he spent to win the game. What is the best way to count and save the time if it is better than the worst times like a leaderboard or record.

Also i have 3 levels (dificulty) : Easy, Medium, Hard. 
So they have to be saved in different files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that the visual-studio tag should only be used for problems with visual-studio itself and not problems with code created within visual studio.

Comment: For counting, saving the value of DateTime.UtcNow at the start of the game and comparing it to the value at the end should be precise enough to give you the time taken.

Comment: Too broad question. Short answer, you could serialize the results to a file in the bin folder and deserialize it once needed. Json and a custom object to register elapsed time, difficulty level and then compare it to the new results.

Comment: I will give you my the usual disclaimer: Windows Forms and other Desktop UI technologies are not suited for game development. It can work with purely turnbased, single or hotseat multiplayer games. If you also do not over it with animations. Minesweeper and Solitaire are pretty much the upper end of what is possible. If you want to get serious in game development, XNA is a dated option. While these 3 are a bit more current: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/gaming But in the end, anything that has a "game loop" should work.

Comment: @Christopher Oh yh i know bro. But it's for school. In programming class we have to do this for 1 module :) We can only use Windows Form so thats why I choose Minesweeper! :P

Comment: Are you basically asking how to write to a file?

Comment: @LordWilmore 1 part of my question is basically that, but I think I will be able to get it. The main thing is to get the time...

Comment: @RafaelGuerra if you just want the time then there are many ways to achieve this, but the simplest thing would be for you to look at the `StopWatch` class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).  It has very simple controls for starting, stopping, resuming, and getting the total time.

Comment: The short answer is, you should be able to figure it out how to get the time, just try searching Google. I know it's hard when yih first start, but if you don't try you'll never succeed. When you have a code problem then come here

Comment: @TheGeneral Thx i will look it up :)

Comment: @LordWilmore Thanks. I will check it out now! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to only store it locally, you could try using Settings.

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty = "your value"
```

Your could then grab them before pasting the new score and compare which time is faster and save it.